# How to customize authenticate() method in social secure module in play frame work 1.2.4

Tags: playframework, securesocial

I want to customize authenticate() in the controllers.securesocial in play framework 1.2.4 as i need to validate few things before login to my application which uses play framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to validate your stuff in your custom class extending `UserServicePlugin`, example in scala and java is available [here](http://securesocial.ws/guide/user-service.html):

```
class MyUserService(application: Application) extends UserServicePlugin(application) {
  /**
   * Finds a user that maches the specified id
   *
   * @param id the user id
   * @return an optional user
   */
  def find(id: UserId):Option[Identity] = {
    // implement me
  }

  /**
   * Finds a user by email and provider id.
   *
   * Note: If you do not plan to use the UsernamePassword provider just provide en empty
   * implementation.
   *
   * @param email - the user email
   * @param providerId - the provider id
   * @return
   */
  def findByEmailAndProvider(email: String, providerId: String):Option[Identity] =
  {
    // implement me
  }

  /**
   * Saves the user.  This method gets called when a user logs in.
   * This is your chance to save the user information in your backing store.
   * @param user
   */
  def save(user: Identity) {
    // implement me
  }

  /**
   * Saves a token.  This is needed for users that
   * are creating an account in the system instead of using one in a 3rd party system.
   *
   * Note: If you do not plan to use the UsernamePassword provider just provide en empty
   * implementation
   *
   * @param token The token to save
   * @return A string with a uuid that will be embedded in the welcome email.
   */
  def save(token: Token) = {
    // implement me
  }


  /**
   * Finds a token
   *
   * Note: If you do not plan to use the UsernamePassword provider just provide en empty
   * implementation
   *
   * @param token the token id
   * @return
   */
  def findToken(token: String): Option[Token] = {
    // implement me
  }

  /**
   * Deletes a token
   *
   * Note: If you do not plan to use the UsernamePassword provider just provide en empty
   * implementation
   *
   * @param uuid the token id
   */
  def deleteToken(uuid: String) {
    // implement me
  }

  /**
   * Deletes all expired tokens
   *
   * Note: If you do not plan to use the UsernamePassword provider just provide en empty
   * implementation
   *
   */
  def deleteExpiredTokens() {
    // implement me
  }
}
```

Those methods are called during the whole login process lifecycle in your play application using securesocial plugin.